# Android Bitmap - What is nativeBitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, native

So I was looking in the source code of the bitmap class and I saw this:

```
public final long mNativeBitmap;
```

What is the native bitmap long? It surely can't be the actual bitmap because a long is 64-bit (8 bytes) which can't handle a bitmap bigger than 2 pixels (supposing the bitmap is ARGB_8888 so 32 bits per pixel). But the `mNativeBitmap` is used in all draw methods which use a Bitmap.

What I though is the following: the bitmap is loaded to the memory into a "bitmap pool" and is given a long identifier to be used later (something like the soundpool). When you draw it you need its identifier, just like when playing a sound from the soundpool. And I thought the `mNativeBitmap` is the identifier. Now, why do we need a `Bitmap` class for this? I supposed we need it for all the native methods that use this identifier and the data that is saved into it upon loading (width, height, density etc.). Now, considering everything written, I have some questions:

Is what I am thinking about it true? Or at least partially true? If not, what is the native bitmap long?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you would have read the first line... "the source code of the bitmap class"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Android frameworks, a long member called `native` anything is usually a platform pointer (a C/C++ pointer) stored in an integer. The bitmap object is allocated in native (C/C++) code, and the pointer to that object is stored on the Java object as a long.

They use a `long` because that is a 64-bit type, and can this hold a pointer value on both 32- and 64-bit architectures.

Comment: Thanks! I really got confused about what that was.